# (Cocos2D) Child already add CCMenuItemImage?

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to change the image of my CCMenuItemImage on the fly like this:

```
- (void)playOrPauseMusic {
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    CCSprite *newSprite;
    if (itemImage.tag == 50) {
        [musicPlayer pause];
        newSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image1.png"];
        playstopButton.tag = 51;

    } else {
        [musicPlayer play];
        newSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image2.png"];
        itemImage.tag = 50;
    }
    CGPoint scale6 = CGPointMake(164 / newSprite.contentSize.width,
                         48 / newSprite.contentSize.height);

    [newSprite setScaleX:scale6.x];
    [newSprite setScaleY:scale6.y];
    [itemImage setNormalImage:newSprite];
    newSprite.color = ccc3(128, 128, 128);
    [itemImage setDisabledImage:newSprite];
}
```

The problem is, whenever this method gets called this crash occurs:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'child already added. It can't be added again'
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, after you setNormalImage, the newSprite object has a parent (the imageItem object). When you setDisabledImage with the SAME newSprite object, coco is probably whining because the sprite object is already in a CCNode hierarchy somewhere (ie nil!=newSprite.parent) .

You may want to create a newSpriteEnabled object and a newSpriteDisabled object, then set color to newSpriteDisabled, and take it from there.